# Многоязычность на php

Tags: php

Делаю себе сайт и не могу сделать многоязычность с параметрами:

1. Чтобы слова в `tpl` выводились допустим `{lang_info}`-инфо.
   А в файле языка, было бы
   info-"инфо".
   Что нибудь на подобии, если плохо объяснил извените.
2. При выборе языка в название было бы `site.ru/ru` или `site.ru/en`.

Как это  сделать?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Передавать в строке параметр языка.
site.ru?lang=ru site.ru?lang=en
При помощи mod_rewrite привести ссылки к виду
site.ru/ru site.ru/en
ну и сделать что то вроде

```
if ($_GET['lang'] == 'ru')
{
 include('lang/ru.php');
}
else 
{
 include('lang/en.php');
}
```

ну а в файлах ru.php en.php

```
<?php
# ru.php
$info = 'инфо';
?>

<?php
# en.php
$info = 'info';
?>
```

В шаблоне выводите {info}
[mod rewrite](http://www.egoroff.spb.ru/portfolio/mod_rewrite.html)
[Шпаргалка по mod rewrite](http://www.exlab.net/tools/sheets/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Не до конца понял как это реализовать.

Answer (score 2):

Определите какой язык у пользователя, после этого в конфиге например, пропишите следующее:

```
$l = 'ru';
// создайте 2 файла ru.php и en.php

if ($l == 'ru') include_once('ru.php')
if ($l == 'en') include_once('en.php')

// в этих файлах можно создать массив, примерно так
$lang = array('error' => 'Ошибка', .. => ..)
```

А потом где нужно, вызывайте так:

```
 <p><?=$lang['error']?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дык [gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.gettext.php) же.

Comment: Спасибо, но я если честно не понял что там) из-за плохого знания англ и php.